# Comparar strings com acentos, UTF-8

Tags: php, string, acentuação

Alguma coisa me está a escapar aqui, estou a fazer o curl a uma página de meteorologia, se os resultados tiverem acentos e comparando com exatamente a mesma string por extenso esta condição retorna falso (não é igual). Isto é meramente para testes:

```
function get_page($url) {

   $curl = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, True);
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
   /*curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS, 1000);*/
   $return = curl_exec($curl);
   curl_close($curl);
  return $return;

}

$weather = get_page("http://www.accuweather.com/pt/pt/cascais/274007/weather-forecast/274007");

preg_match('/<span class="cond">(.*?)<\/span>/s', $weather, $cond);
preg_match('/<strong class="temp">(.*?)<span>/s', $weather, $temp);
$condition = trim($cond[1]); //Céu Limpo (hoje)
$temp = trim($temp[1]); //27 (hoje)
```

No caso de hoje (30-06-2015) a condição que temos é "Céu Limpo", mas quando testo a seguinte condição:

```
if(strtolower($condition) == "céu limpo") {
   ....
}
```

Retorna falso (os comandos dentro do if não são executados)

Mas se fizer:

```
$hey = "Céu Limpo";
if(strtolower($hey) == "céu limpo") {
   ....
}
```

Já retorna verdadeiro e o código dentro da condição já é executado. Gostaria de saber o porquê disto e como resolver

Comment: da um `echo $condition` pra ver o que ele está pegando

Comment: Está a imprimir "Céu Limpo"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seu problema está relacionado com [Html Entities](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp), se você fizer isso aqui:

```
$arrayCondition = str_split($condition);
$arrayString = str_split("Céu Limpo");
var_dump($arrayCondition);
var_dump($arrayString);
```

Você vai notar a diferença na saída deles:

> array(14) { [0]=> string(1) "C" [1]=> string(1) "&" [2]=> string(1) "#" [3]=> string(1) "2" [4]=> string(1) "3" [5]=> string(1) "3" [6]=> string(1) ";" [7]=> string(1) "u" [8]=> string(1) " " [9]=> string(1) "L" [10]=> string(1) "i" [11]=> string(1) "m" [12]=> string(1) "p" [13]=> string(1) "o" }
>
> array(10) { [0]=> string(1) "C" [1]=> string(1) "�" [2]=> string(1) "�" [3]=> string(1) "u" [4]=> string(1) " " [5]=> string(1) "L" [6]=> string(1) "i" [7]=> string(1) "m" [8]=> string(1) "p" [9]=> string(1) "o" }

A primeira que vem do seu **cURL** está vindo com *HtmlEntities*, sua letra <kbd>é</kbd> está vindo com o valor `&#233;`

Pra resolver isso pode utilizar o [html_entity_decode](http://php.net/html_entity_decode), exemplo:

```
if (strtolower(html_entity_decode($condition)) == "céu limpo") {
    echo 'funcionou!!!';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

O problema ocorre porque provavelmente não está em UTF-8 a resposta do CURL.

Para isso tente converter para utf-8 antes de fazer a comparação.

> Funções que podem ser usadas: [utf8_encode](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.utf8-encode.php) ou [utf8_decode](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.utf8-decode.php)

Exemplo:

```
if(strtolower(utf8_encode($condition)) == "céu limpo") {
....
}
//Caso não funciona tente ao contrario as vezes seu arquivo não esta em utf-8

if(strtolower(utf8_decode($condition)) == "céu limpo") {
....
}
```

Comment: Neste caso não resulta, mas boa solução para outros casos. Obrigado